# Can I Import Excel Worksheet to Java and Sort By Cell Info

Tags: java, excel

I would like to know if through Java i can compare the values in columns A to seperate out only each person's name and then further seperate out what the largest number in column B would be.

So basically i want to find the best time for each runner

I would mostly just like to understand if the question is possible and a little bit about how.

Say i have an excel spreadsheet where column A has the name of participants of a track team. These names are repeated multiple times.

Column B has the run times in seconds of each runner throughout a season.

Column C has the date of the time.

```
A                 B                     C
John             20                    1/26/2012
John             18                    1/27/2012
John             17                    1/28/2012
Cindy            21                    1/26/2012
Cindy            20                    1/27/2012 
Cindy            18                    1/28/2012
```

Answer (score 3):

If you [export Excel file as CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) you may:

- Load it with a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)
- split each line of text into an array of String by [String.split( ";" )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
- convert column B to integer with [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
- convert dates to be sortable as YYYY/MM/DD by String.split( "/" ), concat [2]+[1]+[0]
- make instance of Person (a user defined class) with name, time and date
- add person to a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [sort list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) as you want with a [user defined comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party library like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org) for loading the data. Once you have your data model loaded, you can do whatever you find appropriate with it, including the sorting.